# How to use Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul as SSL reverse proxy

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-cloud

I've setup a simple Spring Boot application with Spring Cloud Zuul via `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation as reverse Proxy for some other backend applications deployed as separate microservices.

The zuul reverse proxy is acting as an API gateway in front of the various backend services.

Since this API gateway is the only external reachable destination, it also acts as single secured entry point via HTTPS. The proxied backend services are not secured separately, so they just using plain HTTP.

In the past I was using Nginx for this setup and I am now evaluating Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul as an replacement with Eureka service discovery but it seems that Zuul is not adding the required `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` HTTP header.

How can I tell zuul to act as SSL proxy for non-secured HTTP backend services?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that spring-cloud-netflix is adding the `X-Forwarded-*` HTTP headers and therefore responsible for them.

Filed a PR for adding the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to their `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.PreDecorationFilter` at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/515